# ADO.NET Join() syntax and documentation

Tags: sql, ado.net

I'm writing a program for my localhost db, it needs to take information from two databases and display it in a table. I start with

```
db.Table1.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Join(...
```

Where is the **Join** function documented? I want to join Table1 and Table2, which have a common "Id" column. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this [.Join method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx)? And another [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669071.aspx) on MSDN too